# How can I manage which class' background color to take action, if I have an element with a class list?

Tags: html, css

I have two classes with different background colors style. However, if I have an element that has both classes (as a class list), how can I choose which color to get from the two classes?

I know, for example, if I have this in Style:

```
.intro { 
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

and this in Body:

```
<div class="intro">
  <p>HELLO</p>
</div>
```

Then I would get HELLO with yellow background.
HOWEVER, what if I have this in Style:

```
.intro { 
  background-color: yellow;
}
.concl { 
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

and this in Body:

```
<div class="intro  concl"> // a classList with two classes
  <p>HELLO</p>
</div>
```

How can I manage which class background color to take action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to consider the "Specificity" of the CSS classes you are applying. The more specific rules will be applied over the less specific ones.

You can also create a new class that has the shared CSS rules. This will help you reduce repetitive code, making it more maintainable. For example:

```
<div class="intro concl background">
  <p>HELLO</p>
</div>

.background {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.intro {
    // intro specific stuff
}
.concl {
    // concl specific stuff
}
```

You can find more details about Specificity here: [How is specificity calculated?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 0):

you can't set in html wich class is prior to another for element. but you can set this in css:

( codepen: [link](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/gJNWpL) )

```css
/* if an element had two classes */
.intro.concl{
   background-color: yellow; 
}
/* you can also customize it for each class or id */
#elem1.intro.concl{
   background-color: red; 
}
```

each class can also make it prior to aothers by `!important;`, for example:

```
.intro { 
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```